# Translate data options in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

i have to translate, this data (i have this code in seeds.rb):

```rb
availability_locations = ["Limited", "Locale", "Regionale", "Nazionale", "Internazionale"]
```

what are the options of this form in views:

```html
 <div class="col-xl-6">
      <%= form.association :availability_location,
                           :required => false,
                           label: t('location'),
                           hint: t('please_enter_your_geographic_area'),
                           input_html: {class: 'form-control', "autocomplete" => "off"},
                           wrapper_html: {class: 'form-group'}
      %>
 </div>
```

how can I translate them?

how can i do?

Comment: This is just backwards in so many ways. `seeds.rb` is typically used with the `rails db:seed` command to seed your development database with dummy data and the `I18n` module is not in any way intended for translation of your data - rather its used to translate "fixed" strings in your views such as labels.  If you need to localize your database data you want gems such as Mobility.

Comment: The code in `seeds.rb` also doesn't even do anything. You're just defining a local variable which will just go out of scope as soon as the process finishes. You should probally ask us about the original problem that you're trying to solve instead of this attempt. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#:~:text=The%20XY%20problem%20is%20asking,trouble%2C%20you%20ask%20about%20Y.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the [SimpleForm](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form) gem to build your forms?

If so, check out the README for how to configure I18n (internationalization)

https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#i18n